# How to un-float an aside and move it below content in responsive WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, responsive-design

I am working on my first responsive custom theme and I've run into a couple of snags but the kicker is this one.

I have an aside that I float to the right so that the main content will flow around it. On the mobile version, though, I need for the aside to be BELOW the content.

How do I do that?

Here is the page: http://digitaldemo.net/landmark/whats-in-it-for-you

Many thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 0):

Link is not working.

Anyway, Responsive uses media queries + fluid margins/padding and widths. You can actually do some media queries  like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) { aside { float:none; } }
```

You can play with media queries.

Comment: I've tried that but because the aside is floated right, it has to come before the content in the code. Un-floating it just leaves it sitting there above the rest of the content.

Comment: You must put the aside tag after the content tag. It won't affect anyway.